# Using SweetAlert with preventDefault()

Tags: 7, javascript

I have an event on a form submit.

I set `preventDefault()` to stop the form submitting then pop SweetAlert with a confirmation callback. If they decide to go ahead, it POSTs the form to Drupal.

It doesn't hit the form submission method, but it redirects to the same page with a GET request. If I simply return `true` from the jQuery submission event, it works.

When they confirm, `form.off('submit').submit()` is executed, but it doesn't work.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Do you mean https://sweetalert.js.org/?

Comment: It's actually SweetAlert 2. https://sweetalert2.github.io/

Answer (score 0):

I solved this.

Drupal uses the `$op` variable, which contains the label of the used submission button. When `preventDefault()` is used, that value is removed.

The solution is adding this to the SweetAlert callback function when a form is submitted.

```js
formE.off('submit');
var input = $("<input>").attr("type", "hidden").attr("name", "op").val("Update");
formE.append(input);
formE.submit();
```